# create object properties dynamically by a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object

```
var containers = {
    1: [],
    2: [],
    3: [],
    4: [],
    5: []
};
```

and this object only works, if I will have 5 containers. Is it possible to have something like this

```
var domContainers = $(".container");

var containers = {};

for(var i = 1; i < domContainers.length; i++){
// add a new property to the object
// i: []
}
```

Comment: `containers[i] = [];` See the linked dupetarget for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!:

```js
var domContainers = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
var containers = {};
for(var i = 1; i <= domContainers.length; i++) {
    containers[i] = [];
}
console.log(containers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= domContainers.length; i++){
  containers[i] = [];
}
```

You will have to loop `domContainers.length` times, since you're starting from `1`.